# Deletion of cookie in iframe of another domain

Tags: cookies, iframe

We are trying to delete the cookies in iframe (hosted on domain2) embedded in another domain (domain 1) when the user logs out which we are not able to do so although we are able to set up the cookies while logging in. When tried to delete while opening the same iframe url in the browser, the cookies are getting deleted.

We are setting the cookies in this way :

```
document.cookie = "name="+state.name+";SameSite=None; Secure;expires="+new Date().getTime()+(24*60*60*1000)+";path=/";
```

We are removing the cookie in this way:

```
document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;path=/;'
```

How can we delete these cookies when the user logs out ?